# Type 'import("c:/Users/hp/Desktop/Angular/gametask1/src/app/models/Event").Event[]' is not assignable to type 'Event[]'

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, observablecollection, angular9

I am getting the following error in my component file, when I am trying to store the firebase fetched events in the parameter. The parameters are fetched properly but I am not able store them. What cahnges should I make to run the code?:-

```
Type 'import("c:/Users/hp/Desktop/Angular/gametask1/src/app/models/Event").Event[]' is not assignable to type 'Event[]'.
Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'Event': bubbles, cancelBubble, cancelable, composed, and 18 more.
```

Event.ts:-

```
export interface Event {
    id: string;
    code: string;
    name: string;
    password: string;
    pollCat: string;
}
```

events.service.ts:-

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore , AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Event } from '../models/Event';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventsService {

  eventsCollection : AngularFirestoreCollection<Event>;
  events: Observable<Event[]>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) { 
    this.events = this.afs.collection<Event>('Events').valueChanges();
  }

  getEvents()
  {
    return this.events;
  }
}
```

events.component.ts:-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventsService } from 'src/app/services/events.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-events',
  templateUrl: './events.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./events.component.css']
})
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {

  events: Event[];

  constructor(public eventsService: EventsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventsService.getEvents().subscribe(events => {
      this.events = events;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not import the right `Event` interface into your component.

Add this line in your `events.component.ts`

```
import { Event } from '../models/Event';
```

It compiles because Event is also a global interface, but it's not the one you wanted to use.

Use different names for your interfaces if you dont want those 'conflicts'.